# .click(); not working in browser but works in codepen

Tags: javascript

here is the code I'm trying to use, works in codepen but not on my site. The rest of the functions are working fine but this one is not.

```
document.getElementById("firstOpen").click();
```

here is the error chrome is throwing:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"
```

Not sure how to resolve this, it is part of a clickable tab system, all this is meant to do is open the first tab.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not provide a link to your codepen?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with `click`. You must not have an element in the page with a ID of "firstOpen".

Comment: Yes. What @Carcigenicate said. Or that your script runs before the elements are available

Comment: @QueueSolutions you're welcome